# General Trigger that updates a Master/Detail table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I've been tasked with creating a generic Trigger(one that will work on all tabled in my database) that will will fire on Insert, Delete, and Update to capture changes done on a table.

I have 2 new tables a Master Table...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA_HIL_Master](
   [MasterId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [ReferenceTable] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
   [ReferenceId] [int] NULL,
   [OperationType] [smallint] NULL,
   [Last_UserId_Log] [int] NULL,
   [Last_WorkstationId_Log] [int] NULL,
   [Last_DateTime_Log] [datetime] NULL,   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED     (
   [MasterId] ASC    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS
= ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]    GO
```

And then a Detail table...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA_HIL_Detail](
   [DetailId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [MasterId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [ColumnName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
   [OriginalValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
   [ModifiedValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED     (
     [DetailId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]    GO
```

My trigger needs to be able to update these tables with the correct information for that update and than table.   For Instance I have another table..

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CNF_Tax2Package](
     [Tax2PackageId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [TaxPackageId] [int] NOT NULL,
     [TaxId] [int] NOT NULL,
     [Last_UserId_Log] [int] NULL,
     [Last_WorkstationId_Log] [int] NULL,
     [Last_DateTime_Log] [datetime] NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
         [Tax2PackageId] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
  OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Tax2PackageId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

EveryTime a record is change in this CNF_Tax2Package table I need to up the History tables with information

I do the following UPdate statement

```
   Update CNF_Tax2Package
      set TaxPackageid = 1,
       Last_UserID_Log = 1098,
       Last_WorkstationID_Log = 77,
       Last_DateTime_Log = Getdate()
     where Tax2PackageID = 2]
```

I would insert into the DATA_HIL_Master a row with the following information

```
         [MasterId] = (NEWMasterID)     [ReferenceTable] = 'CNF_Tax2Package'    [ReferenceId] = 2                 ---This is the primary Key of the 
                                      ---table updated.     [OperationType] = 'Update'  [Last_UserId_Log] = 1098    [Last_WorkstationId_Log] = 77   [Last_DateTime_Log] getdate()
```

I would then insert into the DATA_HIL_Detail the following rows.

```
[DetailId] = (NEWID)    [MasterId] = (NEWMasterID) (From above)     [ColumnName] = 'TaxPackageid'   [OriginalValue] = '19'  [ModifiedValue] = '1'

[DetailId] = (NEWID)    [MasterId] = (NEWMasterID) (From above)     [ColumnName] = 'Last_UserID_Log'    [OriginalValue] = '1954'    [ModifiedValue] = '1098'

[DetailId] = (NEWID)    [MasterId] = (NEWMasterID) (From above)     [ColumnName] = 'Last_WorkstationId_Log'     [OriginalValue] = '55'  [ModifiedValue] = '77'

[DetailId] = (NEWID)    [MasterId] = (NEWMasterID) (From above)     [ColumnName] = 'Last_DateTime_Log'  [OriginalValue] = '2018-08-18   [ModifiedValue] = getdate()
```

Understanding that the trigger must be generic enough to handle all tables in my database with different columns, different primary Keys

Comment: You need a trigger on the table to capture changes to the data in that table. But honestly rolling your own like this is not what you want to do. I would think that something like [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) would be a much better solution for you.

Comment: I assumed this is for SQL Server and added that tag. If that assumption was wrong please changed for the tag of the DBMS you're actually using.

Comment: We thought thru CDC and out understanding about CDC is not a long term storage solution.    and Yes this is for Sql Server

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? Since 2016 you can have SQL Server do the heavy lifting for you by changing all your tables to [temporal tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) - However I have to agree with Sean - manually writing triggers for each table is going to be a hard an tedious work, and writing a single generic trigger that could fit all tables will be a terribly hard thing to do, even for experienced DBAs, and a maintenance hell since a DML trigger can only be associated with a single table.

Comment: We are a software company so our clients range from sql server 2008R2 - 2016.